# Couldn't set new column name using AS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to create a new column for the respective `IIF` loops, and in the process, give them a new column name so that they will be printed nicely out in the output. But when I tried to execute, I got a syntax error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

I tried removing the `AS ...` from each line of `IIF` statements, and I can successfully retrieve the result - just without the column names.

Here is my query before I remove `AS`:

```sql
SELECT product.productName, price.basePrice, price.promotionValid, discount.finalPrice,
    IIF(((DATEDIFF(dd,startPromotion,GETDATE()) >= 0) AND (DATEDIFF(dd,GETDATE(),endPromotion) >= 0)),
        IIF(price.promotionValid = 0, price.basePrice,
            IIF(discount.promotionType = 0 AND discount.discountMethod = 0, (discount.finalPrice - price.basePrice) AS currencyDiscount,
                IIF(discount.promotionType = 0 AND discount.discountMethod = 1, (price.basePrice / discount.finalPrice)*100 AS percentageDiscount,
                    IIF(discount.promotionType = 1, (discount.finalPrice/discount.bundleQuantity) AS unitPrice, price.basePrice)))), price.basePrice)
FROM product
INNER JOIN price ON price.productName = product.productName
INNER JOIN discount ON price.productName = discount.productName
```

Comment: What is this _output_ error, when you remove `AS` from the query?

Comment: my bad. i think it was my phrasing of my question that confused you. It was successfuly after i removed the `AS` from the query. I have edited the question already. So sorry :(

Comment: Use `CASE WHEN` rather than `IIF` Its make your query more clear and faster.

Comment: What are the expected column names?

Comment: @BiNZGi hi sir, the column names will be: **productName, basePrice, promotionValid, finalPrice**. Either **currencyDiscount, percentageDiscount or  unitPrice** will also be included depending on the `TRUE/FALSE` result of the `IIF` statement.

Comment: The code in your question currently has IIF expressions nested five deep. You can't assign column names to the nested expressions, only to the outermost IIF expression. If you want to return three columns `currencyDiscount`, `percentageDiscount`, `unitPrice`, then each of those will need to be independent IIF or CASE-WHEN expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot conditionally assign column names to your column. Suppose that you would get three resulting rows. In each row, a different IIF-result is calculated and thus its meaning may be different. How should the column containing those values be called then?

You could include all three additional columns. Or you could create a "generic" column that holds your "calculation" results.

Either way, you need an additional column that will indicate the result type (either base price, currency discount, percentage discount, or unit price).

For some inspiration, I included my variant of your query here. It includes all of the above strategies. Note that I first converted your nested `IIF`s to a `CASE`-block. I tried to be as careful as possible, but I have not tested the query, so it may contain bugs.

```sql
SELECT
  product.productName,
  price.basePrice,
  price.promotionValid,
  discount.finalPrice,
  -- separate calculation result fields:
  discount.finalPrice - price.basePrice AS currencyDiscount,
  (price.basePrice / discount.finalPrice) * 100 AS percentageDiscount,
  discount.finalPrice / discount.bundleQuantity AS unitPrice,
  -- single column containing the conditional calculation result:
  CASE
      WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, startPromotion, GETDATE()) >= 0 AND DATEDIFF(dd, GETDATE(), endPromotion) >= 0 THEN price.basePrice
      WHEN price.promotionValid = 0 THEN price.basePrice
      WHEN discount.promotionType = 0 AND discount.discountMethod = 0 THEN discount.finalPrice - price.basePrice --currencyDiscount
      WHEN discount.promotionType = 0 AND discount.discountMethod = 1 THEN (price.basePrice / discount.finalPrice) * 100 --percentageDiscount
      WHEN discount.promotionType = 1 THEN discount.finalPrice / discount.bundleQuantity --unitPrice
      ELSE price.basePrice
  END AS calculationResult,
  -- column indicating the effective result type:
  CASE
      WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, startPromotion, GETDATE()) >= 0 AND DATEDIFF(dd, GETDATE(), endPromotion) >= 0 THEN 'base price (promotion not active)'
      WHEN price.promotionValid = 0 THEN 'base price (promotion not valid)'
      WHEN discount.promotionType = 0 AND discount.discountMethod = 0 THEN 'currency discount'
      WHEN discount.promotionType = 0 AND discount.discountMethod = 1 THEN 'percentage discount'
      WHEN discount.promotionType = 1 THEN 'unit price'
      ELSE 'base price (no promotion found)'
  END AS calculationResultType
FROM
  product
  INNER JOIN price ON price.productName = product.productName
  INNER JOIN discount ON price.productName = discount.productName
```

Comment: Yep! it works like gem when i tried to fit in. Thank you so much. This is my first time that i realised there is such a great difference between the usage of `IIF` and `CASE` arguments in sql, for i thought that they were the same thing in the past. Once again ,thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. :) `IIF` can be handy for short conditional expressions, but `CASE` is more sophisticated. It has two possible structures: `CASE expression WHEN value1 THEN result1 WHEN value2 THEN result2 ELSE result3 END` or `CASE WHEN expression1 THEN result1 WHEN expression2 THEN result2 ELSE result3 END`. And a `CASE`-expression is also supported in a query's ORDER BY clause to allow conditional sorting. So it's very powerful. It pays off to check [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) and get familiar with it.